# How can I delete test data left behind by Rspec's before(:all) hook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I found out that using `before(:all)` in my specs  [generates test data that is NOT rolled back](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions) after the specs are run. I didn't know that I needed to use an `after(:all)` hook to delete them. Now my test database is filled with those records and I would like to reset it. How can I get this done? There doesn't seem to be a `db:test:reset` rake task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also run

```
rake db:test:prepare
```